# How to check if someone voted for discord bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add a thing where people get coins for upvoting my bot. I tried searching for answers but could now find any. Is there a way to do this with @client.event?

Comment: What voting service do you use? Discord bot list?

Comment: I use top.gg for my bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the documentation: https://dblpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference

You will have to use the events in your bots, and preferably a cog.