# Is this the proper setup for rewarding a user for upvoting my discord bot? (using discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to reward a user who upvotes my discord bot, and I found a way to do this, but I feel as though I likely did something wrong here.
I found this method here:
[How to check if someone voted for discord bot discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466952/how-to-check-if-someone-voted-for-discord-bot-discord-py)
Which in turn led me here: (from the first answer)
https://dblpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#event-reference
Which led here for "the returned data":
https://docs.top.gg/resources/webhooks/#bot-webhooks
This is (part of) my code:

```
@client.event #in case it's important, I use client.event, though topggpy API reference (1st link), used bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    #this is where all the bot's commands go (too long to paste, and unneeded)

async def on_dbl_vote(data):
    id=str(user)+"_stats"
#below this comment is just rewarding the user for voting, and should all work fine
#it all uses replit's database storage, and has worked fine in other things
    if id in db.keys():
        dict=db[id]
        dict["money"]+=1500
        dict["seeds"]+=2
        db[id]=dict
```

My concern here had to do with the fact the if I were to run this, I feel I would get an error for not defining "user". A variable named "user" is also used for different purposes earlier in my code, but if it used that value, it still would not work right. How do I get the variable "user" from "data"? Top.gg documentation (2nd link) lists the variable type for "user" as "snowflake" (which despite my googling, I don't know the meaning of, or how to use).

I could theoretically test this by upvoting my bot, but I'd have to share my bot on Top.gg (and it's not complete enough for me to want to), likely create an alt account on discord (since I doubt I can upvote my own bot (when I tried to look up whether or not I could, all I got was ads)), and then hope my bot notices me upvoting it. And then I doubt it would actually work, and I'd come back here with a problem anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the variable "user" from "data"?

The docs say `data` is a `dict`:

> Parameters:   data – The data with vote info returned **in dict object**

So you can just do `data["user"]` to get the data. If you'd like to get some more precise info on what the data looks like, just print it to your terminal and see what comes out.

```py
print(data)
```

> documentation lists the variable type for "user" as "snowflake" (which despite my googling, I don't know the meaning of, or how to use).

Snowflakes are Discord's way to represent unique ID's. Docs: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes

You won't have to worry about what a snowflake is or how it works.

Ps consider not calling your variable `dict`, that's the name of the built-in dictionary type.

```py
        dict=db[id] # Pick another name
        dict["money"]+=1500
        dict["seeds"]+=2
        db[id]=dict
```